# Laravel larasearch elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using [this package](https://packagist.org/packages/iverberk/larasearch) in my Laravel app (actually 5.5 isn't supported so I forked the repo and fixed the issues [here)](https://packagist.org/packages/norgul/larasearch).

I have enabled `Searchable` trait on my models, and when I'm reindexing I can see that models are actually being reindexed in batches.

On top of that I see that I have a `larasearch:paths` command available also.

Is there a way to actually see within Laravel what has been indexed, and what paths are made since the search I use doesn't work unless I specify for example a full name of the article I'm searching.

The code used to work, so I don't believe it is a search issue, but rather the indexing one.